# Change Git submodule paths recursively

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a huge list of sub modules whose URLs must be changed:

```
 - from URL = ssh://git@sw-depot.sss.foo.com:8080/base/submodule_name.git
 - to   URL = ../../base/submodule_name.git
```

How can I do this using *git submodule foreach*, without using any other scripts?

I have used python script to fetch all URLs and replaced required string literals but I would like to know if there is way to do it with regex in Git.